# How to do this action using Merge Condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a source table and Destination table 
Initailly I loaded some data into destination table through some conditions

```
Target.col1         = Source.col1
AND Target.col2         = Source.col2

MERGE INTO dbo.TestDestination AS Target
USING ( select col1,
col2,
col3,
col4
  from testsource ) AS Source
            ON      Target.col1         = Source.col1
                    AND Target.col2         = Source.col2


    WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN 
    UPDATE
        SET Target.col1 = Source.col1,
            Target.col2         = Source.col2,
            Target.col3         = Source.col3,
            Target.col4         = Source.col4


    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
    INSERT  
        (   [col1]
           ,[col2]
           ,[col3]
           ,[col4]
 )
       VALUES
       (Source.[col1]
       ,Source.[col2]
       ,Source.[col3]
       ,Source.[col4]);
```

but after that i added some more conditions like

```
Target.col1             = Source.col1
AND Target.col2         = Source.col2
AND Target.col3         = Source.col3
AND Target.col4         = Source.col4
```

then data will get filtered. So initial data is wrong data as per conditions so i need to delete initial data and load latest filtered data with these conditions.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how to delete the data of initial load with 2 conditions and insert the data with 4 conditions

Comment: What about adding a DELETE statement to delete the data you don't want to keep? I do not yet understand what the problem is.

Comment: i will give you clear picture initially i loaded data from source to destination on these conditions Target.col1             = Source.col1
AND Target.col2         = Source.col2
and after that i again loaded data from source to destination again adding 2 more conditions Target.col1             = Source.col1
AND Target.col2         = Source.col2
AND Target.col3         = Source.col3
AND Target.col4         = Source.col4 so data will be filtered. So initial data loaded is wrong according to these conditions . I need to delete that data and load fresh data on these given consditions

Comment: Why not do this? `DELETE FROM Target WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Source WHERE {2 Conditions here})`. Then execute the `MERGE`.

Comment: can you me that in example i am unable to proceed on this one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42778/discussion-between-mohan111-and-usr)